# VBA query refresh code in form button: query not refreshing correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a form in excel that has a button on it. The intention is that, when the button is clicked, an SQL query is refreshed, the time and date are calculated and stored on a hidden sheet and the button label is updated with the time and date from the hidden sheet (so that the button always shows the date and time of the last refresh).

This is the code that I've written....

```
Private Sub CheckTBsQueryRefreshBtn_Click()
Dim LastRf
CheckTBsQueryRefreshLbl.Caption = ("Getting Data")
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CheckTbs").Refresh
LastRf = ("Last Refreshed: ") & Now
Sheet47.Range("CheckTBsLbl").Value = LastRf
CheckTBsQueryRefreshLbl.Caption = LastRf
End Sub
```

I'm finding that, when the button is clicked, I get 'Connecting to data source' and then 'Running background query....' with a spinning globe - but, the query doesn't actually refresh.....the globe keeps on spinning and the query will only complete if I close the form.

Am I missing something from my code?

Comment: Have you tried adding in `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CheckTbs").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = false`?

Comment: That works! - I had all of my individual queries set to not use background query, I guess the ActiveWorkbook.Connections("").Refresh method tries to use background query by default thus causing a conflict.

Comment: Glad that's sorted it. I don't know why it defaults to allowing background queries!